# MYSQL - How to fix slow query that is not using indexes, how to speed up response time?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have read several other posts and pages and i can't figure a way to speed up and use an index instead of a full table scan

1. Query in question

```
    select f.*,ci.item_name 
    from forecastpro.current_item_forecast f 
        left join cat_items as ci on f.item_number=ci.item_number
```

2. Tables Structures

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `current_item_forecast` (
      `Axe3` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe5` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe7` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe11` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Item_Number` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
      `Item_Name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `fc_year` int(4) NOT NULL,
      `fc_period` int(2) NOT NULL,
      `Qty_Forecast` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `USD_Forecast` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `Stock_Start` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `Stock_Transit` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`Item_Number`,`fc_year` DESC,`fc_period`),
      KEY `Item` (`Item_Number`),
      KEY `Axe3` (`Axe3`),
      KEY `Axe5` (`Axe5`),
      KEY `Axe7` (`Axe7`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

     CREATE TABLE `cat_items` (
      `Item_Number` char(32) NOT NULL,
      `Item_Name` char(128) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe3` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Item_Group` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe5` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe7` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Axe11` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `Date_Created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Item_Number`),
      KEY `Item` (`Item_Number`)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
   ```
3. Explain

   ```
   id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
   1   SIMPLE  f       ALL                 121882  100.00  
   1   SIMPLE  ci      ALL                 36838   100.00  Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
   ```
4. Other Attempts

   ```
   **This two produce the same result:**

   update forecastpro.current_item_forecast f
       left join cupfsa.cat_items ci on f.item_number=ci.item_number
   set f.item_name=ci.item_name

   update forecastpro.current_item_forecast f
       left join cupfsa.cat_items ci FORCE KEY FOR JOIN (PRIMARY) on f.item_number=ci.item_number
   set f.item_name=ci.item_name

   id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
   1   UPDATE  f       ALL                 76953   100.00  
   1   SIMPLE  ci      ALL                 36838   100.00  Using where
   ```

Any attempt to run simply runs forever.

What would you recomend?

Comment: Your query updates the full table since there's no filtering condition. That's a bad start for index usage.

Comment: @TheImpaler - That statement applies to the first table (est. 121882 rows), but not to the seconds (est. 36838 rows), which _should_ have been something like a `eq_ref` (1 row).  See my Answer for the subtle cause.

Answer (score 2):

For your first select query, you may try adding the following index to the `cat_items` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON cat_items (item_number, item_name);
```

This ideally should speed up the left join process, as each record in the `current_item_forecast` table gets matched to the `cat_items` table using the `item_number` as a lookup.  Note that we also include the `item_name` in the index so as to cover the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Yeah, this will speed up the process. It's a covering index on `cat_items`. +1

Comment: This won't help that much.  Sure, it is "covering", but so is the `PRIMARY KEY(item_number)` since it is clustered with the data.  That is, adding this 2-col index will not help much, if any.

Answer (score 0):

(Thank you for supplying the `CREATE TABLEs`; the root cause in your problem would have been very hard to figure out without them.)

Do not mix `CHARACTER SETs`, at least not when `JOINing` by varchars.  It leads to a costly table scan.

```
current_item_forecast:
    `Item_Number` varchar(40) NOT NULL ... DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
cat_items:
   `Item_Number` char(32) ... DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Be consistent in lengths (40 vs 32).

Since `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique key, don't redundantly include `KEY` for the same column:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`Item_Number`),
KEY `Item` (`Item_Number`)
```

Use `VARCHAR` unless the column is truly fixed width.